# Regex to get string between nearest match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a scenario to get string between two words but the start words repeats multiple times in the text file and the end word is unique. I want the entire string between the last start word and the end word

I tried regex to get multiple matches- It returns the entire string from the first start word to end word.

Then Used Loop condition and removed the same start word and executed. But this ways takes a long time and not good pratice too.

```
Segmentmatch = Regex.Match(text, String.Format("Segment(.*?)0091",), RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

FULL TEXT:

```
Segement DTM*  Tag DTM                                                  
0374:2*                       DATE/TIME QUALIFIER

Segment R4*    Tag R4  
0115*                       PORT OR TERMINAL FUNCTION CODE

Segment R2A*   Tag R2A  
1431*                         PREFERENCE                                                                    
0091:3*                       TRANSPORTATION METHOD/TYPE CODE
```

Expected Result: Text between the last segment and 0091

```
R2A*   Tag R2A  
1431*                         PREFERENCE
```

Actual Result: Code returns entire Text between the first segment and 0091

```
DTM*   Tag DTM                                                  
0374:2*                       DATE/TIME QUALIFIER

Segment R4*    Tag R4  
0115*                       PORT OR TERMINAL FUNCTION CODE

Segment R2A*   Tag R2A  
1431*                         PREFERENCE
```

Comment: If the Segment part and 0091 occur twice, don you expect 1 match https://regex101.com/r/AQXU3z/1 or do you expect 2 matches https://regex101.com/r/AQXU3z/2 ?

Answer (score 1):

To match the last occurrence of Segment and capture in a group until matching 0091.

```
.*\bSegment[ \t]+(.*)\r?\n0091\b
```

- `.*\bSegment` Match any char 0+ times including newline, then match `Segment`
- `[ \t]+(.*)` Match 1+ tabs or spaces and any char 0+ times
- `\r?\n0091\b` Match newline and 0091

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5cbSegment%5b+%5ct%5d%2b%28.*%29%5cr%3f%5cn0091%5cb&i=Segement+DTM*++Tag+DTM++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0d%0a0374%3a2*+++++++++++++++++++++++DATE%2fTIME+QUALIFIER%0d%0a%0d%0aSegment+R4*++++Tag+R4++%0d%0a0115*+++++++++++++++++++++++PORT+OR+TERMINAL+FUNCTION+CODE%0d%0a%0d%0aSegment+R2A*+++Tag+R2A++%0d%0a1431*+++++++++++++++++++++++++PREFERENCE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0d%0a0091%3a3*+++++++++++++++++++++++TRANSPORTATION+METHOD%2fTYPE+CODE&o=s)

[image]

Comment: OP does not need any `(?s)` modifier as OP is already using `RegexOptions.Singleline` and the dot already matches a newline here.

Comment: When I use the same regex .net. The entire text from the first Segment DTM to 0091 is returning. How to use match function in C# to return the result in groups.                 Regex r = new Regex(".*\\bSegment[ \t]+(.*)\r?\n0091\b", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(text);

Comment: @Raj94 I have added a screenshot where you can see that the match already is in group 1. If the Segment part and 0091 occur twice, don you expect 1 match https://regex101.com/r/AQXU3z/1 or do you expect 2 matches https://regex101.com/r/AQXU3z/2 ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Gotcha Thanks a lot.. C# code to get from group                 Regex r = new Regex(".*\\bSegment[ \\t]+(.*)\\r?\\n0091\\b", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                   MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(text);
                foreach (Match ItemMatch in matches)
                {
                    Group g = ItemMatch.Groups[1];
                    string SegmentName = ItemMatch.ToString();
                }

Comment: @Raj94 Did you see my other question about which of the 2 matches you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this if the start and end words are all constants.

```
// LastIndexOf is the magic here
var segmentIndex = yourString.LastIndexOf("Segment");
var startIndex = segmentIndex + 7; // 7 is the length of the start word;
var endIndex = yourString.IndexOf("0091");
var extractedString = yourString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

If the start and end words are not constants, and are instead defined as substrings that match a regex pattern, you could use `Regex.Matches` to find the last match.

```
var lastMatch = Regex.Matches(yourString, someRegex).Cast<Match>().Last();
var startIndex = lastMatch.Index + lastMatch.Length;
var endIndex = Regex.Match(yourString, someOtherRegex).Index;
// same as above
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Raj94 please consider accepting the answer that you think best solves your problem by clicking on that checkmark.